# Arabic encoding in java with linux

Tags: java, linux, encoding, arabic

I am trying to read arabic text from text file and print it in jsp page, but the result displayed is `????? ????`

Note that i wrote my web application in java and deployed to weblogic at linux server.

### Notes:

what encoding does your text file use? windows-1256.

How are you reading it? InputStream.

How are you writing it? redirect the result of input buffer to jsp page by request.

What is the encoding of your JSP? windows-1256.

Have you debugged into the code to find out whether the problem is the reading or the writing? it's work fine when i deployed to windows server

Comment: So what encoding does your text file use? How are you reading it? How are you writing it? What is the encoding of your JSP? How are you specifying it? Have you debugged into the code to find out whether the problem is the reading or the writing? You need to provide *much* more context.

Comment: what encoding does your text file use? windows-1256.                               How are you reading it? InputStream.                                                           How are you writing it? redirect the result of input buffer to jsp page by request.                                                                                                    What is the encoding of your JSP? windows-1256                                    Have you debugged into the code to find out whether the problem is the reading or the writing? it's work fine when i deployed to wnidows server

Comment: Please edit this information *into the question*.

Comment: You'd better post the relevant section of your JSP page, to show what you mean with "redirect the result of input buffer to jsp page by request", and to show whether you have correctly set the charset in the content-type.

Comment: I suspect you didn't set the encoding of the JVM, so it used default system encoding that is different than on windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry guys, i found the solution after many tries, the solution is

```
int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "windows-1256"), BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Comment: It's not a solution to the question that you posted; you haven't posted anything that anyone could derive this from.